# How to check if a number exist between two numbers in java

Tags: java

I have to check whether beam_current value exist between 9.5 and 10.5 at index 1,then at index 2 between 19.5 and 20.5 and so on till beam_current index at 21 and value should lie between 209.5 and 210.5.For this I tried in this way-

```
            int no=0;
            List<Vacc_vs6> new_list=new ArrayList<Vacc_vs6>();
            for(no=0;no<=21;no++)
            {
                String i= ref_jsp.get(no).getBeam_current();
                **for()**//**how to now compare values of beam_current till index 21 and at respective index checking value between 9.95 to10.05,then on next inse 19.95 to 20.05 ans so on**?
            }
What to write in this for loop?????
```

Comment: First of all, if you want to test against floating point values, don't use an int!

Comment: @fge I'm using int for index value.

Comment: after 2 every index should be between 20.95 and 21.05??

Comment: @Prashant I have to check if value at index 1 is between 9.95 and 10.05,at index 2 between 19.95 and 20.05 ,at index 3 value between29.95 and 30.05 and so on till index 21.

Comment: @tiddirastogi so whats this `and value should lie between 20.95 and 21.05.` ??

Comment: @Prashant,Me saying that at index 21 I want to check whether there is any value between 20.05 and 21.05 numbers.

Comment: as per your logic it should be 209.5 and 210.5

Comment: sorry ,u are correct,My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

please change the code as per your requirement but you can use this logic.

```
 int no=0;
 double i = 9.5;
 List<Vacc_vs6> new_list=new ArrayList<Vacc_vs6>();
 double j = 10.5;
 for(no=0;no<=21;no++)// loop is same
 {
     double x;// take index from wherever you want
      // assign value to x before use
     if(x>i && x<j) // check that number between two ranges
     {
         //do your logic
     } 
     else
     {
         new_list.add();// you pass Vacc_vs6 type value in argument of add method
     }
     i +=10;j +=10; // increment the ranges 
 }
```

Comment: double is = 9.5;
     double js = 10.5;
    for(no=0;no<=21;no++)
    {
     String i= ref_jsp.get(no).getBeam_current();
     int im = Integer.parseInt(i);
     if(im>is && im<js) // check that number between two ranges
         {
             //do your logic
         }
         is +=10;js +=10; // i
     }
    }                                                                                                                                 Can I do it in same way.I don't want to use Scanner.

Comment: i said you can change the code specially input part. but you can use this logic

Comment: I want that if the If condition is not satisfied then add zero in the list at corresponding postion.How to do that?

Comment: yes!! and  ` ref_jsp.get(no).getBeam_current()` what is the actual value it will return int or floating type value??

Comment: floating.but I have used rs.getString() for the value

Comment: how to add that else part??

Comment: use double instead of int as `double im = Double.parseInt(i)` and else part added

Comment: I have one doubt how add values of list of class type into another class in java.This logic I want to do in my if and else .

Comment: PLEASE SEE THE LINK **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980138/how-to-assign-values-from-list-of-class-type-into-another-list-based-on-values-p**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72745/discussion-between-prashant-and-tiddi-rastogi).

Comment: it showing error when I use **double im = Double.parseInt(i)** The error is **double im = Double.parseInt(i)  is undefined for the type Double**

Comment: sry its Double.parseDouble(i);

Comment: its bit of confusing!!